# Last Date of the Month in Postgres Sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can we get last day of the month through month name in Postgresql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way :

```
select date_trunc('month', to_date('January ', 'Month'))+'1month'::interval-'1day'::interval
```

To parse a date object from a month name you can try this way :

```
to_date('January', 'Month')
```

Comment: Thanks Alerot. But, I would like to pass month name(like: January) instead Current_date.Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  
    DATE_PART('days', DATE_TRUNC('month', NOW()) 
        + '1 MONTH'::INTERVAL - DATE_TRUNC('month', NOW())
    )
```

You can use any date instead now

Comment: Thanks Starko. I just edited my question. Can you Please look into that again?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (date_trunc('MONTH', now()) + INTERVAL '1 MONTH - 1 day')::date;
```

Comment: Thanks Chandran. But I would like to pass month(Like: January) in now() place. Is It Possible?

Comment: You need give now format like  not just month name try giving '2015-05-12 00:00:00'